# Auto expand the height of event in Kendo-Scheduler?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to set the height of the event Dynamically.

I tried eventHeight inside views. It changes all events height. I need a way to auto resize the eventHeight depends on the length of texts.

Here is something I want, but I can't find a way to do the same thing in the Kendo-Scheduler.

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/details/auto-expand-the-height-of-the-appointment-to-accomodate-the-entire-subject-in-month-view

Comment: on what view day/week/month ? the height of the kendo scheduler event is describing it's duration in day and week view (i think you could some other way to do what you want maybe a hover tooltip and a ...)

Comment: on month view only, the height on month view can only set by eventHeight. And I am not able to set that as auto. Also, I need to adjust the row height dynamically by the different amount of events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following rule to your CSS file:

```
.k-event {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, It works for events. Do you know how to auto expand the height for each row if I want to show all event inside month view?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305024/show-all-events-on-month-view-in-kendo-scheduler

Comment: After I add this, the events are overlapping the previous one. The start position is still default value. Any css I can prevent this?

Comment: If I understand this right, you want the table cells of the scheduler to change size as well?

Comment: If so, unfortunately there is no simple solution like CSS. The only way is to do it yourself using code. You can go over all the events, get their date and height of the element and go to the appropriate `tr` and set its height accordingly.